# How to use Fluent Validation in Repository Pattern in .Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I have made an CRUD operation in .Net core Repositoy Pattern and trying to implement FluidValidation but i am getting runtime error " TypeLoadException: Method 'GetValidationVisitor' in type 'FluentValidation.AspNetCore.FluentValidationObjectModelValidator' from assembly 'FluentValidation.AspNetCore, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7de548da2fbae0f0' does not have an implementation".

My Code is

```
public class ActivitiesService : AbstractValidator<Activity>,IActivitiesService
    {
        private readonly DataContext _dataContext;

        public ActivitiesService(DataContext dataContext)
        {
            _dataContext = dataContext;

            RuleFor(x => x.Title).NotNull();
            RuleFor(x => x.Description).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.Category).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.Date).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.City).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.Venue).NotEmpty();
        }

       
        public async Task<AccountResult> CreateActivity(Activity activity)
        {
            var resultMessage = new AccountResult();
            _dataContext.Activities.Add(activity);
            await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return resultMessage;

        }

       
    }
```

ActivitiesService is inheritated from Interface

and my startup.cs code is :

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PreactivitiesDBConnection")));

            services.AddCors(opt => {
                opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy => {
                    policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
                });
            });
            
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
);

            services.AddScoped<IActivitiesService, ActivitiesService>();
            services.AddMediatR(typeof(List.Handler).Assembly);
            services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false).AddFluentValidation(cfg => cfg.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<ActivitiesService>());

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As showed in this link, the problem has been solved by upgrading the FluentValidation.AspNetCore using the latest version.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation.AspNetCore/